# Showing messages / errors - form validation

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

Since I'm new to web development and I want to advance in the right direction, I have a question concerning form validation. So, I have a small form which is supposed to add some information to database. Obviously, for this I need to use PHP. After form is submitted, I need to stay on the same page but I need to send user a message/error beneath the form (if the user has left input field empty or the database transaction has been completed successfully or it has not been completed at all).

This is my form:

```
<form method="post" action="index.php" name="addOperationForm">
    <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Name of operation" name="nameOfSearch"/>
    <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Security code" name="securityCode"/>
    <input type="submit" class="btns" value="Add to dB" name="submitAddSearch"/>
</form>
```

So far I'm using separate PHP file - index.php for establishing connection with database and adding data to database.

To manage sending messages to user, should I use both PHP and HTML code in one (and then somehow echo messages beneath the form) or should I use jQuery (but how can I then establish database connection)? Eventually, what is the correct way of doing this? Please can you post an example?

Comment: This may be classed as too broad, as each person has their own method of showing errors to the user in many different ways. You could store all the errors in an array and spit them out on to the page at once or you could show one error at a time. Using jQuery would make it more interactive but is up to you as the developer. Before worrying about jQuery or even JavaScript I would suggest that you work on your HTML and PHP skills only until you are comfortable with it.

Comment: Can you please tell me what's your way or what do you recommend as correct or good way?

Comment: *correct* or *good* are terms which are defined differently by each person, hence my original comment that this question may be classed as being too broad. One persons good might be another's bad. Find a method you are comfortable with and use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is make a php script that will process the validation and return the response in json format so that jQuery can process the request using ajax.

for example in **response.php**

```
<?php
  //Get submitted data from the form
  $name = $_POST["name"];

  //sample validation character is less than 2 char
  if(strlen($name) < 2){
    $response = array(
                "error" => true,
                "message" => "Name should be 2 characters or more"
           );
  }else{
      $response = array(
           "error" => false,
           "message" => "Name is valid"
      );
  }

//Return the response for ajax request
     echo json_encode($response);
```

Now on your **client side (form view)** make ajax request using jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $.ajax({
         url : "response.php", //the php script that will handle the validation
         method : "post"
     }).done(function(response){
        //handle the response
         if(response.error===false){
             //output the response message below the form
             //success has div with class success
             $("<div class='success'>" + response.message + "</div>").appendTo("form[name='addOperationForm']");

             //redirect to a page
             //  window.location.href = "nextpage.php";
         }else{
            //error has class='error'
             $("<div class='error'>" + response.message + "</div>").appendTo("form[name='addOperationForm']");
         }
     });
});
```

To add styling on your success and error class add the following on your css file

```
.success { background-color : #0f0; color : #fff; } /* background is green for success */
.error {background-color : #f00; color : #fff;} /* background is red for error */
```

The code isn't tested but should work on your use case.

Comment: I'll give your code a try.

Comment: Sure pal, I just give you the idea of how it could be done :)

Comment: I have a simple question. When the php script is done, do I use header to go to my html page?

Comment: You can do either ways through php or jQuery, if you do using jQuery or javascript you only need to add window.location.href = "url to html page" on success validation if php then you need to use header. I added the redirect to my answer

Comment: I'm accepting your answer! Thanks for help

Comment: No problem glad to help :)

Comment: `str_len()` that isn't a core PHP function, the function is `strlen()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php

Comment: sorry for the typo, I wrote the code on the spot. :) corrected the type, thanks for spotting...

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery for form validations (empty checking)

**form**

```
<form method="post" action="index.php" name="addOperationForm">
    <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Name of operation" name="nameOfSearch"/>
    <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Security code" name="securityCode"/>
    <input type="button" id="submit_btn" class="btns" value="Add to dB" name="submitAddSearch"/>
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    //capture button click event
    jQuery('#submit_btn').click(function(){
        var err = 0;
        jQuery('.input').each(function(){
            //if input is empty, increment err variable
            if(jQuery.trim(jQuery(this).val()).length == 0) err++;  
        });
        if(err == 0) jQuery('#form').submit(); //submit form when err is 0
        else alert("Please fill out the form completely");
    });
});
```

Comment: Why is *this* the correct way to validation? Consider explaining your code, as the OP is new to web development.